# how to use one function variable into another function?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, cartridge

I have two function in **Django Templates.**

```
def cart(request, template="shop/cart.html"):
 cart_formset = CartItemFormSet(instance=request.cart)

def checkout_steps(request):
```

How I use the **cart_formset** variable in my **checkout_steps function.**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  That's what local variables are: they're local to the function they're in.  The variable `cart_formset` does not exist except when `cart` is executing.

You could return `cart_formset` from the function and then call `cart` from `checkout_steps` to get the value.  Or you could store that variable somewhere else.  I don't know enough about Django to know where the best place is.  Given that what you're doing looks like a shopping cart setup, I would guess that you want to store that info with the session, so you could look at Django's session handling.

Answer (score 1):

> How I use the cart_formset variable in my checkout_steps function..

1. If the two functions are related, use a Class (like Shopping) and
   add cart and checkout_steps as member functions.

   ```
   class Shopping(object):
       def __init__(self):
           self.cart_formset = None
       def cart(self, request, template="shop/cart.html"):
           self.cart_formset = CartItemFormSet(instance=request.cart)
       def checkout_steps(self, request):
           #Use self.cart_formset
   ```
2. You can also put the variable cart_formset, as global to make it available globally across the module

   ```
   def cart(request, template="shop/cart.html"):
        global cart_formset
        cart_formset = CartItemFormSet(instance=request.cart)
   def checkout_steps(self, request):
        #Use self.cart_formset
   ```
3. If the order of function evaluation is deterministic then you can use a decorator

Comment: When I use this as a globally or in class.It shows error.
class Shopping(object):
 def __init__(self):
  self.cart_formset = None          
def cart(self,request, template="shop/cart.html"):
 cart_formset = CartItemFormSet(instance=request.cart)
 -
def checkout_steps(self,request):
-
 qwert = self.cart_formset
 context = {"form": form, "CHECKOUT_STEP_FIRST": CHECKOUT_STEP_FIRST,
      "qwert":qwert}
 return render(request, template, context) 
ERROR IS:
TypeError at /shop/cart/
cart() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)